# Is it possible to integrate Google translation in iOS App programmatically (Swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift, google-translate

I have to translate the data coming from API in my app. For which I need to integrate Google Translate or something that can translate the data that is coming from backend.
How do I start coding this?

Comment: Your question might be off-topic because: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"... However, are you looking for something like [this](https://github.com/prine/ROGoogleTranslate)?

Comment: Thanks for the reference Ahmad. Actually I asked the question thinking that  any one might have done it already.

Comment: @AhmadF your refernce worked. Thanks for help man!! :)

Comment: Could you post it as an answer, @AhmadF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *specific* SDK for the iOS platform for Google translation.

However, you could achieve it by "manually" requesting the translation API(s). For more information, check the [Google Cloud Translation API Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/).

**Furthermore**: Using [ROGoogleTranslate](https://github.com/prine/ROGoogleTranslate), might save some time, therefore you would be able to do it like this:

```
var params = ROGoogleTranslateParams(source: "en",
                                     target: "de",
                                     text:   "The sentence to be translated")

let translator = ROGoogleTranslate(with: "API Key here")

translator.translate(params: params) { (result) in
    print("Translation: \(result)")
}
```

Comment: This still works in 2022.

Answer (score 2):

You can use google Translator URL to translate text inside your Application.
Follow the example.

```
        let selected_language = "en"
        let target_language = "hi"
        let YourString = "hello"

        let GoogleUrl = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + selected_language + "&tl=" + target_language + "&dt=t&dt=t&q=" + YourString
```

After creating the `GoogleUrl`  perform a Get Request from this URL using `urlSession` or `Alamofire` this url will return you json responce of translated text.

Comment: Is there no limit for this request ? I dont know so I ask to you. Thanks

Comment: no there are no limit for this requests. since this is simple url request you dont need Any API key etc.

Comment: I think there is a limitation on googleapis. Also it has got pricing list.

Comment: this url is not using google API for translation, we are just using standard web Url for translating text.

Comment: There is a limitation on your IP I think .

Comment: i am using this in various Applications. i didn't found any limitations

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ajaysaini. Is it possible to convert the set of content like any array or dictionary, as in my app, I'll have to convert the whole set of data?